# How to make calls from c# to Drupal API

Tags: c#, asp.net, drupal, drupal-8

A customer has a Drupal database. As I saw in drupal docs it's possible to make request to drupal API https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/jsonapi/fetching-resources-get . All I want it's to make calls from my c# code to Drupal API for fetching all data that I need. So only GET(SELECT) requests. So the question is:

1) Is it possible? I didn't find any examples.

2) Where can I see the domain of a client Drupal database?I need it in these requests according to the link above.

3) Do I need to specify any request auth headers? Some token or API Key?

If you have any information about it please share. Thanks you in advance.

EDIT
As I can see there was a guy who tried something similar. But he didn't fetch data but just login to the dropal node [Consuming Drupal RestApi with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567883/consuming-drupal-restapi-with-c-sharp/39610884)

Comment: You need to read about how to call rest APIs from C#. There are multiple ways you can do it. Using HttpWebRequest or using RestSharp libraries.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Question is more about how to call Drupal API, which headers are required and is it possible at all or not. Maybe I got the documentation wrong.

Comment: When it comes to HTTP API's, client and server do not care what language each other are implemented. All they need to care about is that they communicate using agreed upon standards such as HTTP and JSON. And since almost every programming language has support for HTTP and JSON, there's no point in asking if it's possible. You can just assume it is. As far as examples, you just need to learn how to consume an HTTP API in the language of your choice. You don't have to find specific examples of consuming Drupal from C#.

Comment: Hey Vlad, there are a couple ways to do this, depending on how Drupal is configured -- check with that site admin. Drupal 8 has two common modules for this JSON:API and REST. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/jsonapi/jsonapi-vs-cores-rest-module Also you have some options for authenticating, tokens, basic auth, and others provided through modules. Personally, my preferred way of making API calls to Drupal 8 is by creating a custom View in REST format. That gives the easiest way to control the output, like field names and format, etc.